# Detecting if something exists and then automating process

Tags: php, automation, detection, bigtable

I was wondering if it would be possible to write a script in PHP which would proceed through an extremely large data set (100 million+) to try locate specific strings within the data set?

If it is feasibly possible would it be an efficient form of identifying a keyword within the dataset?

If there is a better way of processing through such a large dataset to try an detect a string I am all ears

Comment: Everything is possible in programming.

Comment: This is an interesting question but so broad that it may be closed soon. Can you specify a little more about the constraint, the type of file, db connection, etc.

Comment: Yes Sébastien, I was asked by a Google representative to try and find ways to detect and automate google adword policy violations. So for example if someone has put copyrighted content within their google adword content. Now as far as I am aware Google uses BigTable as their database, so I presume all of the data is within this database. If you have a better way other than using a script as I said im all ears!

Answer (score 2):

Well like Jari said everything is possible in programming.

I deal with large data via Hadoop, MapReduce etc.